# Computer Power supply fan not spinning with proper voltage

Tags: power-supply, dc, computers, fan

I have a computer power supply which had 4 blown filter capacitors (3 2200uF/10V and 1 1500uF/16V).  The power supply is now working as far as powering a computer goes, however the cooling fan is not.  I jumpered the green wire to one of the black wires on the 24 pin main power connector to bring power to the components on the power supply board without having to have it connected to the pc and I replaced the fan with a known good 12V DC 0.5A fan (same as the one that came with the power supply) which did not spin either when connected.  The terminals that the fan connects to on the board are showing ~12.65v.  I was under the impression that as long as voltage was supplied to a dc fan that the fan would spin, what am I missing that is not allowing the fan to spin up?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The power supply may not be able to deliver enough current for the fan to spin. Have you tried measuring the current in the positive wire while the fan is connected and supposed to spin?

Comment: This seems to be the issue, I have never had a situation where I needed to check current before, I assumed that it was related but it turns out that I was testing it incorrectly.  I connected the meter at 10A DC to the fan circuit in series and measured 0.00 amps.  Checking for open circuit now.  Learning experience. Thanks

Comment: Did you figure out why the current is near 0? I have similar situation, I guess. The fan on my PSU got stuck and I don't know for how long it was like that. When I noticed I wanted to replace it but the new fan didn't spin. I checked the voltage it was around 12. Then checked the current and it was around 4mA when it was supposed to be around 160mA. I guess I can take 12V which can provide necessary current from another place on the circuit board but I'm afraid that this situation already means that something else is broken and I wonder if that can be easily repearable?